# How to use concatenate command in SSRS "Code.SumLookup(LookupSet)" function?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The custom code nested in report properties :

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal  
If items Is Nothing Then  
Return Nothing  
End If  
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()  
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()  
suma = 0  
ct = 0  
For Each item As Object In items  
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)  
ct += 1  
Next  
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma   
End Function
```

My command like this :

`=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet("9040101", Fields!norek.Value,Fields!tgl10.Value, "NR_01"))`

if I run that command the result is not error. the value will be 100

than

I just want to make `Fields!tgl10.Value` dynamically change when the parameters also change. so I changed it

from :`Fields!tgl10.Value` to   : `"Fields!tgl" & parameters!nm_kolom.Value & ".Value"`

become this

`=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet("1040101", Fields!norek.Value, "Fields!tgl" & parameters!nm_kolom.Value & ".Value", "NR_01"))`

but I found an #error instead

Is there any missing from the my new command?

Thank You
Regardz

Comment: Edit your question and show the code behind the `Code.SumLookup()` function, otherwise we dont know what happens in the custom code section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your concatenated expression will by a string, but not a field reference. Try this instead:

```
Fields("tgl" & Parameters!nm_kolom.Value).Value
```

Comment: can you give me suggestion, if I want to change the scope with parameter, so it can change dynamically. Code.SumLookup(LookupSet("1040101", Fields!nosbb.Value, Fields("tgl" & Parameters!nm_kolom.Value).Value, "Parameters!nm_tabel.Value")) like the command above, Regardz

Comment: @RukhanZakaria Provided that the nm_tabel parameter contains the valid name of a scope, my first attempt would be to remove the quotes.

Comment: If I use Parameters!nm_table.Value without quotes the result is "The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox12.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for a lookup function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset"